# Play Framework: Configuring system properties

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

In play framework (2.2.1 & sbt 0.13) I have an `IntegrationSpec` that brings up a `TestServer`. I need to be able to set SSL specific System Properties for the `TestServer`. So far the only way I have been able to set it up correctly is passing them as command line properties like below

```
play -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=... -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=.... -D... test
```

I want the tests to run simply using `play test`. For that in Build.scala I configured SBT javaOptions as follows

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    Keys.fork in Test := false,
    javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf")
```

And in application.test.conf I set all the system properties. With this the `TestServer` is not even using `application.test.conf`. I was not able to figure out why. So I thought I will try the following:

```
play -Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf test
```

The `TestServer` did use `application.test.conf` but none of the system properties (javax.net.ssl.keyStore="..." etc.) configured in the file were being used.

So I have two questions

1. How to have this running only using `play test`? . (I do not want to pass a long Map of properties to `FakeApplication` in `TestServer`).
2. When I run `play -Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf test`, why are the system properties configured in `application.test.conf` not being used?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution using the .conf file?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works for setting a property for reading the configuration file, but you can set your individual properties with `System.setProperty` like this:

```
System.setProperty("application.secret","psssst!")
```